# Is there a phase coexistence line below the critical temperature $T_c$ in normal to superfluid transition?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, superconductivity, phase-transition, superfluidity, critical-phenomena

In the case of water, there is a phase coexistence line (called the liquid-gas coexistence curve) which ends in a critical point. And this line separates the gas phase from the liquid phase in the P-T phase diagram.

*1. Do we observe such coexistence line below $T_c$ in the case of normal to superfluid transition below the critical point?*

*2. If yes, what are the phases that this line separates?*

Comment: Could you sketch the phase diagram that you're visualizing? I understand what you mean by "phase coexistence," but I don't understand the "phase coexistence *line*" that you're considering.

Answer (score 1):

The liquid and the gas have the same symmetries, so the phase transition line can end in a critical point. The fluid and the superfluid do not have the same symmetries (the superfluid has a broken $U(1)$ symmetry), so the phase transition line cannot end.

The simplest possibility is that at any pressure the superfluid transition is at lower temperature than the liquid-gas transition. In this case there are two different lines, which never meet. Below the critical pressure of the liquid-gas endpoint you encounter two transitions when you cool the gas. The first is liquification, the second is superfluidity. Above $P(crit)$ there is only one transition, which is the superfluid transition. The phase diagram of liquid helium does indeed look like this.

Comment: The coexistence is between liquid-gas. Not between liquid-fluid or gas-fluid where by fluid I mean the phase above $T_c$. I'm asking what happens below $T_c$. Below $T_c$ there is normal fluid and the question of normal fluid coexisting with superfluid doesn't make sense. @Thomas

Comment: @SRS Sorry, I misread your question. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A phase coexistence line is a first-order transition. I believe that the superfluid transition is always second-order, so there is no phase coexistence line.

Comment: Dear @tparker Would you like to comment as to why this is the case?